# Run elf linux file in a bash loop with parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run an elf file in a for loop using bash under Linux, but getting some strange result:

If I do

```
for i in {1..50}
do 
    echo "$ i iteration"
done
```

Iteration goes from 1 to fifty as intended, but when i add my elf file with parameter

```
for i in {1..50}
do 
    echo "$ i iteration"
    /home/test/app/print -write
done
```

echo is stuck at iteration 1, and goes all the time as 1. What could be the problem

Comment: Have you copied the code right? What's the extra `}` for? What's with the space between `$` and `i`? Don't rewrite code in the question, copy-paste actual code instead.

Comment: What does print do?  If it is waiting for input from the user, the thread running the bash loop will be suspended..

Comment: `for i in {1..50}` (get rid of the extra `}`). Your problem is probably due to `/home/test/app/print -write` blocking while waiting for something to write. Without knowing what is in `/home/test/app/print`, we would just be guessing -- post that.

Comment: print is an elf file not a command, its a simple program that takes couple of system information and prints them out when use -write command

Comment: Did you compile `print` from C, Java? -- regardless, it is obviously your problem if the loop executes properly without it and then chokes with it. What happens when you run `/home/test/app/print -write` from the command line?? (I bet it just sits there...) Call your script with `bash -x scriptname` for debugging output.

Comment: Its from C, and when i run it manually it works fine, no need for additional parameters, I've even tries without -write parameter to print out just app info in that loop, and stuck at 1, outside its ok.

Comment: you can add strace before the command to see the last system call : `strace /home/test/app/print -write`